# Problema de validación Auth en Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, login, auth

un saludo a toda la comunidad, soy nuevo en esta plataforma. Estoy revisando un proyecto hecho en Laravel 4.2 (en subdominio), específicamente la parte del login y tengo problemas al mostrar un mensaje en la vista, después de validar una sesión, es decir ingreso mi usuario y contraseña (ambos incorrectos), doy click en un botón iniciar sesión , se muestra la ruta donde se hace la validación de sesión (aparece en 2 segundos un pequeño mensaje diciendo Redirecting to mi subdominio), me redirecciona nuevamente al login (por credenciales incorrectas) pero no me muestra el mensaje personalizado de credenciales incorrectas. Y cuando pongo credenciales correctas me redirecciona al dashboard admin pero ahí mismo redirecciona al login nuevamente. Aquí les dejo el código de 5 archivos:

1. login.blade.php

```
<div class="login-form">        
  <div class="login-content">           
    @if (Session::has('login_errors'))
     <p style='color:yellow'>El nombre de usuario o la contraseña no son correctos.</p>
    @else
     <p style='color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)'>Introduzca usuario y contraseña para continuar.</p>
    @endif

    <form action="login" method="post" role="form" id="form_login2">                
      <div class="form-group">                  
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="entypo-user"></i></div>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" autofocus />
          </div>                    
         </div>

     <div class="form-group">                   
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="entypo-key"></i></div>                     
         <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>                
 </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-login" id="socket">
       <i class="entypo-login"></i> Iniciar Sesión
      </button>
    </div>                              
   </form>
                    <br />
                    <div class="login-bottom-links">                        
                       <!-- <a href="password/reset" class="link">¿ Olvido su contraseña ?</a>  -->
                    </div> 
                            
                </div>      
            </div>
```

2. LoginController.php

```
<?php

class LoginController extends BaseController {

    public function user() {
        $data = array(
            'username' => Input::get('username'),
            'password' => Input::get('password')
        );

        if (Auth::attempt($data)) {
            return Redirect::to('admin');
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('/')->with('login_errors', true);
        }        
    }
}
```

3. User.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait,
        RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    public function getRememberToken() {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    public function setRememberToken($value) {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName() {
        return 'remember_token';
    }

    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

4. routes.php (extracto)

```
<?php

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Application Routes
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
  | It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
  | and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
  |
 */

Route::get('/', function() {
    return View::make('login');
});

Route::post('login', 'LoginController@user');

Route::get("user", function(){ /*esto creo que no se debe tener en cuenta*/
    $flag       = '01';
    $users      = '';
    $nombre     = 'david';
    $apellido   = 'VERGARA';
    $username   = 'dvergara';
    $password   = Hash::make('123456');
    $tipo_user  = '01';
    $resultado  = DB::select('call sp_users_mantenimiento(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',array($flag,$users,$nombre,$apellido,$username, $password,$tipo_user));
});

Route::get('admin', 
  array('before' => 'auth', function() { 
    return View::make('dashboard.admin');
  })
);
. . .
```

5. admin.blade.php (extracto)

```
@extends("base")

@section("title")
FOSSO - Panel De Administración
@stop


@section("content")


    <div class="panel panel-success" data-collapsed="0"> <!-- panel head -->
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">FOSSO - SISTEMA DE GESTION</div>
        </div> <!-- panel body -->
        <div class="panel-body">


    @if(Auth::user()->tipo_users == '01')
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="dashboard-wid-wrap">
                    <div class="dashboard-wid-content">
                        <a href="catalogo/productos">
                            <img  src="assets/images/shopping_cart.png">
                            <span class="dasboard-icon-title">Productos</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="dashboard-wid-wrap">
                    <div class="dashboard-wid-content">
                        <a href="catalogo/insumos">
                            <img  src="assets/images/insumos.png">
                            <span class="dasboard-icon-title">Insumos</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="dashboard-wid-wrap">
                    <div class="dashboard-wid-content">
                        <a href="catalogo/usuarios">
                            <img  src="assets/images/partner.png">
                            <span class="dasboard-icon-title">Usuarios</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="dashboard-wid-wrap">
                    <div class="dashboard-wid-content">
                        <a href="catalogo/proveedores">
                            <img  src="assets/images/truck.png">
                            <span class="dasboard-icon-title">Proveedores</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="dashboard-wid-wrap">
                    <div class="dashboard-wid-content">
                        <a href="catalogo/trabajadores">
                            <img  src="assets/images/partner.png">
                            <span class="dasboard-icon-title">Trabajadores</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="dashboard-wid-wrap">
                    <div class="dashboard-wid-content">
                        <a href="catalogo/recetas">
                            <img  src="assets/images/recetas.png">
                            <span class="dasboard-icon-title">Recetas</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="dashboard-wid-wrap">
                    <div class="dashboard-wid-content">
                        <a href="/abastecimiento/insumos">
                            <img  src="assets/images/abastecimiento.png">
                            <span class="dasboard-icon-title">Abastecer insumos</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    @endif
```

[image: mensaje de validación no se muestra en la vista]

Creen que puede que no sea problema de lógica?? y pueda ser problema de redireccionamiento o algo por el estilo?? , disculpen mi forma de redactar iré mejorando , por favor ojala me puedan ayudar. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Laravel 4.2 es realmente antiguo y hace años que no tiene soporte. ¿Estás seguro que es la versión de laravel? o será la del instalador? Revisa en el `composer.json` que dice en `"laravel/framework":`

Comment: Hola, gracias por comentar, en composer.json se muestra esta sección: 
"laravel/framework": "4.2.*",